# what is the correct snmptrap command format?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

Which of the following is the correct format for `snmptrap` (net-snmp) command?

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public host "" NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification \
       netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate i 123456
```

or

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public host "" NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification \
       netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate.0 i 123456
```

i.e., with or without `.0` in the variable bindings?

Actually both of these formats work, but which one is right or what is the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends if "scalar" or a "table row"-related varbinds are being referred to in the trap.

http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptrap states :

> Note that this command also includes an (OID,type,value) triple for
> the varbinds listed in the VARIABLES clause (in the same way as with
> the snmpset command).

**Table row example.**

```
snmptrap -v 2c -c public host:162 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3    \
        ifIndex i 2 ifAdminStatus i 1 ifOperStatus i 1
```

For reference :

```
snmptranslate -m +ALL -Pu .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3
IF-MIB::linkDown
```

No `.0` in the variable bindings since id is taken care of by the `ifIndex` which pinpoints the row.

**Scalar row example.**

http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:snmptrap shows example

```
snmptrap -v 1 -c public host UCD-TRAP-TEST-MIB::demotraps "" 6 17 "" \
       SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 s "Just here"
```

'SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0' is a **scalar**.

Unlike `IF-MIB::linkDown` example above, which was related to a table row id-ed by the **ifIndex**,  here the `.0`s  at the end pinpoints the scalar (like when you SET it)

**Netsnmp example from original question**

`mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt` states

```
netSnmpExampleHeartbeatRate OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      Integer32
    MAX-ACCESS  accessible-for-notify
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A simple integer object, to act as a payload for the
         netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification.  The value has
         no real meaning, but is nominally the interval (in
         seconds) between successive heartbeat notifications."
::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationObjects 1 }
```

i.e. it is **not** a real, identifiable, accessible scalar so I recommend no `.0`.

Comment: Actually both works, but which one is right or what is the difference?

Comment: k1eran explained that the 1st one was correct - you can accept its answer

Comment: Please do acept this as the answer - in order to help other searchers in the future